# How to save modified UIImage with original meta data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

In my iOS app, I have to make some modification on a `UIImage`, for example adding a watermark on it. After that, I want to save the image with *original* meta data, but if I tried to using `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:`, I got nothing in the produced image.

Since I have to modify the image, so I have to pass the `NSData` for `metadata:` part using the following method: `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *, float)`.

And right before saving the image, the meta data is like:

```
Meta: {
    ApertureValue = "2.526068811667587";
    BrightnessValue = "-1.807443054797895";
    ExposureMode = 0;
    ExposureProgram = 2;
    ExposureTime = "0.05882352941176471";
    FNumber = "2.4";
    Flash = 16;
    FocalLenIn35mmFilm = 33;
    FocalLength = "4.12";
    ISOSpeedRatings =     (
        800
    );
    LensMake = Apple;
    LensModel = "iPhone 5c back camera 4.12mm f/2.4";
        LensSpecification =     (
        "4.12",
        "4.12",
        "2.4",
        "2.4"
    );
    MeteringMode = 3;
    PixelXDimension = 3264;
    PixelYDimension = 2448;
    SceneType = 1;
    SensingMethod = 2;
    ShutterSpeedValue = "4.058917734171294";
    WhiteBalance = 0;
    "{GPS}" =     {
        Altitude = "147.9932";
        DOP = "76.42908";
        Latitude = "45.7398";
        LatitudeRef = N;
        Longitude = "126.6266";
        LongitudeRef = E;
        TimeStamp = "2013:12:23 08:45:30";
    };
```

So, what is wrong here?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? any console log output? Does the actual code that writes the image get executed?

Comment: No, there's no exception at all..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UIImage *newImage = self.yourOriginalImage;

UIImage *anotherImage = @"waterMark.png";
CGImageRef imageRef = anotherImage.CGImage;

CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(imageRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(imageRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef), NULL, false);

CGImageRef maskedImage = CGImageCreateWithMask([newImage CGImage], mask);
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: maskedImage];
```

Comment: Well, I didn't quite get it.. This code seems to display the image on a imageView, but what I need is save the image into a image file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a UIImage called myEditedImage and the metadata in an NSDictionary (or an NSMutableDictionary...) called "metadata":

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library;
ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock completionBlock = ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {};
float compressionLevel = 0.75; // Or whatever you want
NSData *dataIn = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myEditedImage, compressionLevel);
[library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum: dataIn
     metadata: metadata
     completionBlock:completionBlock];
```